# How to increase speed when drag item from top to bottom of listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scroll

I'm building and android music app, i created playlist song which user can choose any song to add into playlist, but i had problem.

In case of there are many song into playlist (more than 100 or 200 song), if user drag a song from position 1 to bottom of listview, the process for scrolling is very slow. So, is there any solution for increase this issue ?

I also added
`android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` or `getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);` 
but that issue is still happen.

What i have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listview try to implement the *list* with `RecyclerView`.
It is faster and better compared to listview.

Comment: So is there another solution ? RecyclerView is the best solution for that issue, isn't this ?

Comment: Yah, even android developers suggest to go for recyclerview instead of listview.